# unable to test maxLength with mock input enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocking, enzyme, maxlength

I want to test `Input` jsx element for `maxLength`.
My element in react-

```
const ValidatedInput = ({ name, labelName, value, onChange, disabled, maxLength = 10 }) => {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="form-control-label" htmlFor={name}>
                {labelName}
            </label>
            <Input className="form-control" type="text" id={name} name={name} value={value} autoComplete="off"
                onChange={onChange}
                disabled={disabled}
                maxLength={maxLength}
            />
        </div>
    )
};
```

My test is

```
it('should not content more that 10 characters', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<ValidatedInput onChange={()=> {return true;}}
            id={'testInput'}
            value={'1234567890extra'}
            />);
        expect(wrapper.find('input').instance().value).toBe('1234567890');
});
```

I printed value on console it's `'1234567890extra'` & not `'1234567890'` while when tested manually from UI, it worked perfectly.

Comment: What's `Input`? Does it differ from `input`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code uses `max` prop for `Input` *component*, while it is `maxlength` for `input` *element*.

Enzyme [doesn't have features to set input values](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/76). And setting the value through `value` (both property and prop) bypasses `maxlength` restriction, which is intended for user input only. Notice that [it isn't applied to initial `value` prop](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sjammx), this proves that the assumption how `maxlength` works was wrong. A value should be additionally limited in a database where it was stored .

A proper approach for unit tests (which Enzyme is for) is to not test intrinsic browser behaviour or other libraries, this should be saved for E2E tests. It's possible to test that `ValidatedInput` provided correct `maxlength` for `input` with:

```
expect(wrapper.find('input').prop('maxlength')).toBe(10);
```